# Real-Time Windows Target error while build with 'to Video Display' block

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I tried to run in real time a simple acquisition from the webcam and to send it to a `to Video Display` block. I used Real-Time Windows Target selecting `rtwin.tlc` as system target file, fixed-step discrete solver, `32-bit x86 compatible as device type (despite I use 64-bit Windows 7)`; when I try to build it returns the error:

```
Error(s) encountered while building model "untitled"
```

without specify cause of the error. Did I have miss something?

PS: I tried it replacing Webcam acquisition with `From Multimedia File` block and it returns same error.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation, the "to Video Display" does not support rtwin.

> Note   This block supports code generation and is only available on Windows platforms with available file I/O. **This excludes Real-Time Windows Target™** (RTWin). This block performs best on platforms with DirectX Version 9.0 or later and Windows Media Version 9.0 or later.

From Media File can't work as well, rtwin does not support file I/O

Comment: Thanks for reply. Same error returns also with 'Video Viewer' block with 'From Video Device' block, but help does not mention RTWT problems. Some suggestion for a real-time video processing using USB-webcam?